# display_errors is not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to make errors hidden but it seems I'm doing something wrong.
In my hosting configuration `display_errors` is set to `off` and I don't have `.htaccess` file. I tried to write follownng script

```
<?php
    echo ord(ini_get("display_errors")) . " ";
    die("error");
?>
```

And I'm getting following output:

```
0 error
```

So, `display_errors` is set to off, but `die()` function still shows error on the screen. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `error_log()` function. Now I can use

```
function quit($error)
{
    echo "Request failed";
    error_log($error);
    die();
}
```

Comment: trigger_error() doing exactly the same but according to error handling settings, silly.

Answer (score 6):

By doing `die("error")`, you're are commanding the code that it should output the string "error" and stop the code.

You are seeing the "error" message does not mean that there is an error, it is just another string.

`die()` is a function (commonly used to handle errors), but it is not deactivated when you set display errors off. It will still work and to whatever it is meant to do.

Comment: I thought it supposed to output text to stderr instead of stdout

Comment: @Poma, the [exit() docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) make no mention of stderr or stdout. (die() is just an alias for exit().)

Answer (score 1):

> How to avoid this?

**Do not use die()** to handle errors.

use `trigger_error()` instead, which will follow the behavior you expected

Comment: It dont stop the script execution

Comment: Triggering an `E_USER_ERROR` stops script execution. It also puts a log message in Apache's error log (in a normal world).

Comment: @Poma THAT'S WHY you should use it! Because terminating script execution is stupid. At least you have to send 500 error and some user friendly HTML first

Comment: I don't need to do it since I'm writing script for my key management server and only my program will make requests to this script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to display error to `stderr` instead of `stdout` so you won't see them on you webpage, but only in the logs. ([Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors))